# How to display one div on hover of another when both div have same parent?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I want to display anchor tag(takes full height and full width of parent) with transition on hover of first div .Both div and anchor has same parent. Here is my html code.Please suggest any solution using jquery

```
                         <div style="position: relative;">
                            <div class="img-div">
                                <img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/909/flowers-garden-colorful-colourful.jpg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=1&w=500" style="width: 100%;">
                                <p></p>
                            </div>

                            <a class="swiper-slide-anchor " href="#" style="position: absolute;left: 0px; top: 0px;padding: 20px;height: 100%;">
                                <p class="swiper-content-title" style="margin-bottom: 10px;font-size: 18px;color: orange;">Forging</p>
                                <p class="swiperc-content-body" style="font-size: 16px;margin-bottom: 20px;color: black; "> With no restrictions on type, size and weight of materials, our expertise in forging spans across closed-die, cold forging, open-die, rolled ring and more.</p>
                                <h5>Learn More</h5>
                            </a>

                        </div>
```

Comment: Can you add an image for you design so we can imagine it, so to help you.

Comment: would you please add snippet so we can give try

Comment: Please check the link https://jsbin.com/qurehebiwi/edit?html,output . Initially anchor should not be visible. and on hover of div, img should disappear and anchor should be visible with background-color: white. Note: anchor takes full height and width of parent